# Create directory in dockerfile failed , permmision

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im trying to create dir in docker file and I got error during the build

```
FROM circleci/openjdk:8-jdk-browsers

#RUN chown newuser /dep
#USER newuser
RUN mkdir  /dep
```

**The error is:**

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/dep’: Permission denied`
The command `/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /dep` returned a non-zero code: 1
```

even if I try only `dep` .
I try to use `chown` without success, any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image is run with the user `circleci`, you can check this by adding a `whoami` to a `RUN` statement in your Dockerfile. This user has no permission to create folders in `/`. So, you can either create a folder somewhere where this user has the necessary rights (e.g. `/home/circleci/dep`), or you just go with `sudo mkdir`.

Comment: `sudo` usually doesn’t work in Docker, but you can `USER root` easily enough.

Comment: @DavidMaze In this specific case, `sudo` worked. It depends on how the image is configured, I guess.